# Python split, replace

Tags: python

I am writing a scrip and have run into a roadblock.  There is probably a more efficient way to do this, but I am fairly new to Python.  I am trying to create a list of user generated IP addresses.  I am using print to see if the produced values are correct.  When I run this code, the print ip_start has the same value and is not updated.  I am sure this is a fairly simple fix but I have a major brain lock.

```
ip_start = raw_input('Please provide the starting IP address for your scan --> ')
start_list = ip_start.split(".")
ip_end = raw_input('Please provide the ending IP address for your scan --> ')
end_list = ip_end.split(".")
top = int(start_list[3])
bot = int(end_list[3])
octet_range = range(top,bot)
print octet_range
for i in octet_range:
    print i
    print "This the top:" + str(top)
    ip_start.replace(str(top),str(i))
    print ip_start
```

Comment: Is this only for legacy IPv4 or why do you omit IPv6 addresses?

Comment: Yes only for IPV4.  This is just a project to learn more about python.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `replace` method on strings doesn't modify the strings in-place. In fact, *nothing* modifies strings in-place; they're *immutable*. This is explained in the Tutorial section [Strings](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

What it does is *return a new string* with the replacements done on it. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace):

> `str`.**`replace`**(*old*, *new*[, *count*])
>
> > Return a copy of the string with all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. If the optional argument *count* is given, only the first *count* occurrences are replaced.

So, what you want is:

```
ip_start = ip_start.replace(str(top),str(i))
```

Comment: I knew that, darn it!  Thanks for the help!

Comment: So basically, with each iteration the variable ip_start will be assigned a new value but the original object is never modified, a new one is created?

Comment: @user2565554: Exactly. `ip_start` now names the new value, and nothing at all names the (unchanged) original value (which means it's garbage, and will be deleted automatically for you).

Comment: @user2565554: In your code, you might _want_ to keep the original one around somewhere (because otherwise that `replace` isn't going to work after the first time, since `top` won't appear there anymore…), which means you may want to use a _different_ name to get replaced each time through the loop, like `ip_current = ip_start.replace(str(top), str(i))`.

Comment: Thanks! I was just going ask about that!

Answer (score 1):

`ip_start.replace(...)` — just like every other `str` method — does not modify `ip_start`.  Instead, it returns a modified string which you must then assign to `ip_start` if you want to change it.